# how integrating $\sqrt{1-x^4}$

Tags: calculus, integration

i don't even understand how to do this, surely this function is continuous at $|x|<1$ and have real value on that given integral. and
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^4}dx$$ should doable .

but since there isn't any variable outside root, i can't make any substitution of it. i'm trying sought on integral calculator but it said there isn't any antiderivative of this function .

so assuming this question is valid is there any way to solve this? ( i'm currently on mid-end of calculus 1). by the way 
the provided answer just attach half circular image that says "symmetry"  and state $1.748$ is the answer and it doesn't make much sense for me[image]

Comment: You probably have to use elliptic integrals.

Comment: yes, i would like to see how it's done at least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an elliptic integral, which you are probably not expected to know anything about.

But note that $\sqrt{1-x^4}>\sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $-1<x<1$, and therefore
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^4} \, dx > \int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2} \, dx = [\text{area of half the unit circle}] = \frac{\pi}{2} \approx 1.5708
.
$$
So your integral is greater than $\pi/2$,
and alternative (D) looks like a rounded value of $\pi/2$, and (E) is the only number which is larger, so the only alternative which can be correct is (E).

(Strictly speaking, it *could* be (D), since $1.571$ also also greater than $\pi/2$, but that possibility can be ruled out since the difference $1.571-\pi/2$ is so small that the total area between the graphs $y=\sqrt{1-x^4}$ and $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ must be greater.)

Comment: thanks a lot , since answer in worksheet is only make me confuse , it's keep highlighting on integral but not explain the nature of the function itself.

Comment: @pikarin-g: Yes, if that handwritten stuff in the image you posted is supposed to be some kind of official answer key, it really doesn't provide much *explanation*...!

Answer (score 3):

In terms of Beta functions,$$\int_{-1}^1(1-x^4)^{1/2}dx=2\int_0^1(1-x^4)^{1/2}dx=\frac12\int_0^1y^{-3/4}(1-y)^{1/2}dy=\frac12\operatorname{B}\left(\frac14,\,\frac32\right).$$This can be rewritten with Gamma functions as$$\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)\Gamma\left(\frac32\right)}{2\Gamma\left(\frac74\right)}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)\sqrt{\pi}}{3\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)}=\frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac14\right)\sqrt{\pi}}{3\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)}=\frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac14\right)}{3\sqrt{2\pi}}.$$

Comment: thank you i really appreciate that even i'm still far from there , and i'm attached the image of the worksheet . how your thought about it ?